# Changing Inside Assets Folder In Yii Framework

Tags: yii, yii-components

I came to notice that there is one folder called assets in the root folder.To know more about it,I went through [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/) link.Now I want to know adding some css in these files is good or shall I add css to to the main.css file inside css folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good reasons to use Yii's assets.

1. it prevents naming conflicts in css and js files
2. it allows you to keep CSS and JS files under your document-root but outside of your web-root (for easier version control)
3. it allows to easily switch between sets of CSS & JS files, rather than having to deal with each file individually (suppose the system admin needs to revert back to a previous version).
4. it allows you to publish assets (images, JS & CS) to several websites hosted on the same server.

Please check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109494/how-to-reuse-code-across-multiple-domains) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The asset folder is automatically generated by Yii based upon your environment so best avoid putting your CSS, images etc inside here. It also best to not commit these folders and files into SVN as they are automatically generated and folder names will differ from your qa/staging/live site to your local site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when i started my first Yii project, i also put my CSS and JS files in assets. It works but then i found that its not just the right way. Its better to make a separate directory for your CSS file(s). Also there are some auto generated files in assets, so to avoid mix-up with those and your i prefer to make it separate. Hope you got the point.