# Is there a way we can build YII multisite application with one database for multiple domains

Tags: php, yii, cross-domain

We are planned to host a single CMS for the multiple sites.

Is there are way in YII we can do that, The idea is simple we want to share single application and single database for all the domains but we will let them choose the different themes for the different website.

By website I mean totally different Domains.

What other setting will we have to do to point all the domains to single server ?

Edit::

I don't want the different serve directory for each domain. what I want to do it, keep the installation only one.

i.e. 
/server/www/master

then all the domains

a.com, b.com, c.com read the same dir "/server/www/master" and same DB. and records get filer on the base of site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109494/how-to-reuse-code-across-multiple-domains

Comment: Thanks RGB, but that's not i want, I have edited the Question as per my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done exactly that with Yii so yes it is possible.

In your Apache settings make sure to point all the domain names to the same directory (using ServerAlias - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

In my database I created a table with a row for each website, storing the domain name as one of the fields.

In my ApplicationConfigBehavior.php::beginRequest (which is executed for every request), I did something like this:

```
/**
     * Load configuration that cannot be put in config/main
     */
    public function beginRequest()
    {
        if(empty(Yii::app()->session['community'])){
            $current_community = Community::model()->with(array(
                'communityHosts'=>array(
                    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
                    'condition'=>'`communityHosts`.hostname= :hostname',
                    'params' => array(':hostname' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
                ),
            ))->find(); 
            Yii::app()->session['community'] = serialize($current_community);
        }
        else{
            $current_community = unserialize(Yii::app()->session['community']);
        }

        if(!empty($current_community)){
            Yii::app()->name = $current_community->name;
            Yii::app()->params['currentCommunity'] = $current_community;
            Yii::app()->language = $current_community->language;
        }
        else{
            //TODO: Throw error
            session_unset();
            die('Hostname ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .' not found');
        }


    }
```

Which basically says, looks for this server name in my database, get the current "community" (my sites), and store all the settings (theme, site name, etc...) in the session.

The exact query might not be the same for you. It's just to give you the general idea. Adapt it to your database schema or however you store the settings for each website.

Answer (score 2):

In the apache virtual host file, set the site name

```
SetEnv SITE_NAME "CMSA"
```

Get site name in the code using

```
defined('SITE_NAME') || define('SITE_NAME', ( getenv('SITE_NAME') );
```

Use the constant in the config and filter your records based on the site.

The same way theme can also be declared.

Comment: Does "CMSA" donates some specific value ? or its just plain text ? How will the site_name differ on the different domain_name I'm gonna have only one .htaccess

Comment: Consider your domain name is http://cmsa.com. The site_name is short form of the domain name. For sample only, I mentioned it as site_name.  The constant name can be anything as you wish.

These value should be declared in apache virtual host file. Each domain will have different host file.